# jQuery: Turn off delegated events from original object, with namespace

Tags: jquery, event-delegation, jquery-events

I've attached a delegated event handler this way:

```
$('#static-div').on('click.myNamespace', '.attach-to-this', someFunction);
```

How do I then, later, reverse this action and remove all delegated events in that namespace? The `static-div` element is always on the page and only its contents change.

I tried the following, but neither worked:

```
$('#static-div').off('myNamespace');
$('#static-div').off('myNamespace', '**');
```

I feel like this should be easier than it is....

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#static-div').off('.myNamespace');`?

Comment: Maybe that's my problem - I wasn't putting a period before the namespace... I'll try.

Comment: That was it! Yeesh, I really thought I didn't need the period. If you'd like to make a formal answer with that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the period when removing events from a namespace.

For example, `$('#static-div').off('.myNamespace');`

See the docs for more info: http://api.jquery.com/off/